# How use ViewBag to display data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

SchoolController

```
schoolBLL content = new schoolBLL ();
DatabaseSchool  dbSchool = content.GetSchoolInfoById(LoginStaffId);

if (dbschool != null)
{ 
    string textcontent = dbschool .text_content;
}
```

class file

```
public DatabaseSchool GetSchoolInfoById(int StaffId)
{
    return SchoolRepo.Find(a => a.schoolcontent_id == StaffId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So, I am trying to display the data in to a HTML page with this tag

How can I pass the value from the controller into the HTML page ?

I already tried to use **ViewBag** and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying data into an html page try below:

School Controller:

```
schoolBLL content = new schoolBL();

DatabaseSchool dbSchool = content.GetSchoolInfoById(LoginStaffId);
    
if(dbschool != null)
{ 
   TempData["textcontent"] = dbschool.text_content;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <textarea id="txtcontent" class="form-control" rows="20">@TempData["textcontent"]</textarea>
```

Better to use CSHTML:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.TextArea("Content", TempData["textcontent"])
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not working for me it still return nothing I tried on both the cshtml and html

Comment: Have you checked, you are getting data in dbschool.text_content ?

Comment: Check this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-Set-value-to-TextBox-using-TempData-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Is there any reason that dbschool.text_content is not getting data at all .

Comment: Are you getting any data in dbschool first?

Comment: No it returning nothing, I think that the problem is coming from ```SchoolRepo.Find(a => a.schoolcontent_id == StaffId).FirstOrDefault();```

Comment: So that is the problem. Once the data is fetched then it will be passed to the view.
First check by passing a "test" as data into the controller by assigning it to TempData.